# Specific and different question marked as duplicate

Tags: discussion, support

Many discussions about duplicate question are found here.

I'm not trying to show off or to blame anyone. I just want to know if everything goes fine, fair and clear (objectively). What I need is to get more knowledge (to survive) and to share what I know the best I can.

**[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28884463/validator-w3-rss-invalid-rss-not-showing-the-feed-by-using-php)** had been marked as duplicate by a user with a gold badge.

Before I submitted my question, I searched other references related to my question via google, stackoverflow and so on. However, my question still has no solution. That's why I submitted it (no human perfects!). Besides, that link said about general things to generate the RSS issue, not in specific things.

Problem is classified into two:

1. General Problem
2. Spesific Problem inside no. (1)

This can not be seen as one problem!
Is that the way to redirect the popularity? (I'm here to learn and to survive).

As we all know that the OP can be beginner or misunderstanding his own real problem or not accurately/carefully detect what he/she is facing. This should be responded wisely. Remember they themselves in the past time. Are they beginners?

One thing that everybody knows that, perhaps, in the future, THAT "related question" marked as a duplicate question NOT longer used or out of date.

Member with gold badge has **one-click-privilege** and it seems nothing I can do to change anything. I think there must be other controller to monitor if the "gold-click" is really objective or not (at all).

**Please let me know** what I have to do when my question marked as duplicate but, basically, spesifically, no related question exists in there.
Thanks for your wise response.

Comment: I found many as well, why don't you try to edit the question?

Comment: If your question is different than the suggested duplicate then you now need to modify your question to explain why the other does not provide an answer.

Comment: I'd just edited the question, but it seems no work. the duplicate MARK still exist. This can be caused by marker who has gold badge.

Comment: @AdrianHHH, after editing the question, I see new link, named, "reopen". I wonder it refers to remove solved question to be a new question? you can see that my question was successfully solved by other user and I want it keep checked as solved problem.

Comment: Between the time the question was closed as a duplicate and now I see only one fairly trivial edit to the question. That edit does not say anything about why you believe your question is not a duplicate and nothing to lead people to question whether the duplicate status should be changed. Furthermore, the question needs to ask something that may be valuable in the future. The accepted answer is mostly just a link to another website and answers like that are commonly deleted. Time spent grumbling here on **meta** may be a waste of your time compared to spending time improving your question.